# Is it there a way to show all keys in eps schemes with chemnum?

Tags: chemnum

I find the `show-keys` feature from `chemnum` super handy, as it allows me to keep track of all the plenty compounds I use throughout my document. But I ran into a hiccup, which I could not resolve: If I replace keys in .eps schemes generated by ChemDraw, the document crashes, when I use the option `true` or `def`. It does work with the option `ref`, but shows me the keys I declare in the scheme itself, not the referenced ones as indicated by the name. Plus, I need to use `\replacecmpd+{key}` to not crash the compilation. Outside the scheme, everything works fine and as intended. Is there a way to show all the keys in the scheme?

I just noticed while playing around, that the keys are being put into margin, when having them defined, could that be the cause for the crash? If yes, i would be fine with all the keys being put inside the scheme, similar to the `ref`version. I have no idea though, how to do it :D

```
\documentclass[english,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{
    spectroscopy,
    scheme,
    nomenclature,
    mechanisms,
    isotopes,
}

\setchemnum{
    replace-tag={X},%X<#> used as template tag, better visualization in chemdraw file than TMP<#>
    show-keys=ref,
}

\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

Here the numbers are defined: \cmpd{Garner_02} and \cmpd{Garner_04}

\begin{scheme}[htb]
    \centering
    \replacecmpd{Boc-ser-OMe}
    \replacecmpd+{Garner_02}
    \replacecmpd+{Garner_04}
    \replacecmpd{Garner_22}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{garner_rxn}
    \caption{Synthesis of Garner's aldehyde~\cmpd+{Garner_04} and the corresponding Weinrebamide~\cmpd+{Garner_22}.}
\end{scheme}

Here they are referenced: \cmpd{Garner_02} and \cmpd{Garner_04}

\end{document}
```

with
[the eps here (hopefully)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuhg1tblv1l82hz/garner_rxn.eps?dl=0)

Comment: If a package setup lets the compilation crash it is worth a report on the issue tracker: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues

Comment: got it, submitted the report on github just now :) thx for letting me know.